# docker tomcat jdk 11: why debug port 8787 needs to be *:8787?

Tags: docker, debugging, tomcat, port

docker tomcat jdk 11: why debug port 8787 needs to be *:8787?

```
 0.0.0.0:8787 -> 8787/tcp
 -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=*:8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

On host outside docker, the address 8787 works for jdk 11.